# jQuery check if ANY element exists

Tags: jquery

I have this code which is not working
jQuery

```
if($("#dis(h3)").length == 0) $("#dis").append("<p>no display</p>");
```

HTML:

```
<div id="dis">
<h3>Title</h3>
//append here
</div>
```

The append code should work

```
<div id="dis">
<h3>Title</h3>
<p>Text</p>
</div>
```

The append code should not work.

**Edit: I need the append code to appear if there is no other element inside `#dis` beside h3**

What should i do to make it as above(intended)

Comment: [jquery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
if($("#dis > h3").siblings().length == 0) $("#dis > h3").append("<p>no display</p>");
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S2bvk/)

Comment: Not working. I need the append code to appear if there is no other element inside #dis beside h3 Thanks

Comment: @cicakman. editted - tested on jsfiddle - workd for me. Any better